# Xml-RPC Server Python - Multicall requests?

Tags: python, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib, simplexmlrpcserver

Let's assume that my code looks like that:

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

# Restrict to a particular path.
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

# Create server
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000),
                            requestHandler=RequestHandler)
server.register_introspection_functions()

# Register a function under a different name
def adder_function(x,y):
    return x + y
server.register_function(adder_function, 'add')
server.register_instance(MyFuncs())
server.serve_forever()
```

Now let's assume that I have many clients calls, so are there many listing processes of XML-RPC server or clients requests are queued (one request must be ended to serve another)

Is there a possibility to deal with multicall client requests, using Python XML-RPC server ?

Comment: Do you mean something other than using the threading or forking mix-ins?  Those are reasonably straightforward and allow multiple simultaneous(ish) client requests.

Comment: Are you looking for http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html#multicall-objects